# Firefox+IE - how to place a div of 100% height inside a table-cell div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to know how to place a div of  100% height inside a `table-cell` div. I tried by giving `display:inline-block; width:100%;height:100%;` to the div but it is working fine in Chrome and the problem is there in Mozilla and IE.

The fiddle is
http://jsfiddle.net/kQM74/2/

The HTML code is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header width100p">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content width100p">
        <div class="width25p npv">
            <div class="width100p inner">
                <p>navigation</p>
                <p>
                   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="width74p rtb">
            <div class="width100p inner">
                <div class="width100p ql">
                    <p>div one</p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="width100p mtbs">
                    <p>div two</p>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="floatL width100p widdiv">
                    <div class="floatL width100p">
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="floatL width100p">
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatL width40p incont">
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>                      
    </div>
    <div class="footer width100p">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

The respective styles are:

```
<style>
*,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,body,.content{
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

.header h2,.footer h2{
    text-align: center;
}

.floatL{
    float: left;
}

.floatR{
    float: right;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.width100p{
    width: 100%;
}

.width25p{
    width: 25%;
}

.width74p{
    width: 74%;
 }

.header,.footer,.content{
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.npv{
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.ql,.mtbs{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.content{
    display: table;
    behavior: url(display-table.min.htc);
}

.npv, .rtb{
    display: table-cell; 
    -dt-display: table-cell;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.width40p{
    width: 40%;
}

.incont{
    margin: 4%;
    background: #ccc;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

In this I want to know how to place a div(.inner) of  100% height inside a `table-cell` `div`(`.npv`). It is occupying 100% height only in Chrome and not in IE and Mozilla. I want to know the reason of its failure in both ie and Mozilla. Is it possible to achieve the same thing using any other method in CSS? If so then how?

Comment: I could not understand what's the problem.

Comment: the problem is .inner div height is same as .npv div height only in chrome and not in mozilla and ie. I want to know the reason of this cross browser issue I am encountering.

Comment: you don't need to put CSS in `style` tag in the jsFiddle, updated link is here : [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/kQM74/3/)

Answer (score -2):

For `table-cell` elements to work properly they need to be placed inside `table-row` elements, and these ones inside `table` element.

As explained in [specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) if some of these elements are omitted browser will wrap them around anonymous elements of needed `display` type. Supposedly, this is where Firefox fails.

You can try to wrap all your elements in parents with corresponding `display` type - there are elements with `table-row` missing.

*EDIT*: You need to apply `height:100%` for `table-cell` elements. This fixed misbehavior in my FF 24.0.

```
.npv, .rtb{
    display: table-cell; 
    -dt-display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/BtwTh/

Comment: i tried changing the structure as you said by putting another wrapper with display:table-row; but I am still encountering the same cross-browser issue of .inner div height is same as .npv div height only in chrome and not in mozilla and ie.

The updated fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/kQM74/4/

Comment: This doesn't answer the IE problem.